# Partition data into subgroups based on bit fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the first 4 columns of data, and I wan't to use the Ranking functions in the SQL 2008 R2 to derive the fifth column. What's the best way to partition the data into subgroups based on the nextiteminsubgroup and previousiteminsubgroup fields?

```
 Group  OrderInGroup    NextItemInSubGroup  PreviousItemInSubGroup  SubGroup
    1   1   1   0   1
    1   2   1   1   1
    1   3   1   1   1
    1   4   0   1   1
    1   5   0   0   2
    1   6   0   0   3
    1   7   1   0   4
    1   8   1   1   4
    1   9   0   1   4
    2   1   0   0   1
    2   2   0   0   2
    2   3   0   0   3
    2   4   1   0   4
    2   5   0   1   4
    3   1   0   0   1
    4   1   0   0   1
    4   2   0   0   2
    4   3   0   0   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive CTE solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
([Group]  INT 
,OrderInGroup  INT
,NextItemInSubGroup INT
,PreviousItemInSubGroup INT
,SubGroup INT
)

INSERT @t
VALUES
(1,1,1,0,1),(1,2,1,1,1),(1,3,1,1,1),(1,4,0,1,1),(1,5,0,0,2),(1,6,0,0,3),
(1,7,1,0,4),(1,8,1,1,4),(1,9,0,1,4),(2,1,0,0,1),(2,2,0,0,2),(2,3,0,0,3),
(2,4,1,0,4),(2,5,0,1,4),(3,1,0,0,1),(4,1,0,0,1),(4,2,0,0,2),(4,3,0,0,3)

;WITH recCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  [Group], OrderInGroup,NextItemInSubGroup , PreviousItemInSubGroup, 1 AS subgroup
    FROM @t
    WHERE OrderInGroup = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  r.[Group], t.OrderInGroup,t.NextItemInSubGroup , t.PreviousItemInSubGroup, 
            CASE WHEN r.NextItemInSubGroup = 1 THEN r.subgroup ELSE r.subgroup + 1 END
    FROM recCTE AS r
    JOIN @t AS t
    ON t.[Group] = r.[Group]
    AND t.OrderInGroup = r.OrderInGroup + 1
)   
SELECT * FROM recCTE
ORDER BY [Group],OrderInGroup ;
```

P.S. it's best practice to avoid using SQL keywords (e.g. `GROUP`) as table/column names

Comment: Works exactly like required. I accidentally introduced the group when I was trying to generalize / abstract the problem. Next time when I post a question about sql, I'll try to add the data in sql, so it's easier to immediately play with it. Sorry about the extra work and thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like 0 and 0 restart the ranking.

```
Select
      Rank() Over ( 
        Partition By 
          [Group]
        , Case When [NextItemInSubGroup] + [PreviousItemInSubGroup] = 0
               Then 0
               Else 1
          End
        Order By [OrderInGroup]
      ) as [SubGroup]
From Your_Table;
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately for my case, though it does reset the ranking from 0 and 0 as you say. But in this case, it will rank the first 4 items to be 1, 2, 3, 4 whereas they need to be 1, 1, 1, 1